# Counterexample, union of intersections, intersection of unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for an example which illustrates that the following doesn't have to be an equality:

$$\bigcup _{i \in I} \bigcap _{k \in K} A_{ik} \subset \bigcap _{k \in K} \bigcup _{i \in I} A_{ik} $$.

It is quite easy to prove the inclusion: $x \in \bigcup _{i \in I} \bigcap _{k \in K} A_{ik}  \iff \exists i \in I : \ \forall k \in K \ : \  x \in A_{ik} \implies \forall k \in K: \ \exists i \in  I : x \in A_{ik}$

We generally have that $$\exists x  : \ \forall y \ : \phi(x, y) \implies \forall y: \ \exists x : \phi(x, y)$$ and here the counterexample for the reverse implication is taking $\phi(x, y)$ to be the relation $x<y, \ x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

But taking the set $A_{ik} = \{ i \in \mathbb{R}  \ : \ i<k\}$ doesn't work here:

$$\bigcap_{k \in K} A_{ik} = \bigcap_{k \in K} \{ i \in \mathbb{R}    \ : \ i<k\} = \emptyset \ \ \  \text{as} \ \ \  k \to - \infty.$$

And if we take the union  $$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_{ik} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \{ i \in \mathbb{R}    \ : \ i<k\} $$ we don't get anything new, we just get $A_{ik}$.

Am I doing something wrong? Could you please point that mistake out for me?

Comment: Write down the iff condition(necessary and sufficient conditions)  for the second set and you will get the point.An element lies in the second set  is equivalent to lying in every $\cup_{i\in I}A_{ik}$,i.e.,for every k there exists one A_{ik} such that the element lies in A_{ik}.Since you've written down the first set's iff condition,comparing them and you will know the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\forall k\in K\exists i\in I\; x\in A_{ik}$ does not guarantee
that some $i\in I$ exists with $\forall k\in K\; x\in A_{ik}$.

Note especially that for every $k$ the $i$ with $x\in A_{ik}$ somehow depends on $k$.

---

Counterexample:

Let $K=I=\left\{ 1,2\right\} $.

Let $A_{11}=A_{22}=\{0\}$ and let $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ both be sets that do not contain $0$ as element.

You could go for $A_{12}=A_{21}=\varnothing$.

Then $0$ is element of RHS, but not of LHS.

Answer (score 8):

For integers $i, k \ge 0$, let $A_{ik} = [\frac {k+1} {i+k+1}, 1]$.

Then for fixed $i$, $\bigcap_k A_{ik} = \{1\}$, so $$\bigcup_i \bigcap_k A_{ik} = \{1\}. \tag{UI}$$

However, for fixed $k$, $\bigcup_i A_{ik} = (0,1]$, so $$\bigcap_k \bigcup_i A_{ik} = (0,1]. \tag{IU}$$

Thus (UI) is strictly included in (IU).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. It's a pity I cannot accept both...