# Prove or disprove. $\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} = \bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $\{ C_{i,j} : i\in I \text{ and } j\in J \}$ be a family of sets. Assume the set $I$ (of indices $i$) is arbitrary, non-empty, and non-enumerable. Similarly, assume the set $J$ (of indices $j$) is arbitrary, non-empty, and non-enumerable. Prove or disprove the equality $$\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} = \bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}.$$

> **Check my proof of this equality. Any errors?**

To prove that the equality is true, we need to show two inclusions. First, we will show that

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}.$$

Suppose $x$ belongs to $\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}$. This means that there exists an index $i_0$ in $I$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i_0,j}$. For all $j \in J$, we have $x \in C_{i_0,j}$, therefore $x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$ for all $j \in J$. This implies that $x$ belongs to $\bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$, as desired.

Now, let's show that

$$\bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}.$$

Suppose $x$ belongs to $\bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$. This means that for all $j \in J$, we have $x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$. Therefore, for each $j \in J$, there exists an index $i_j$ in $I$ such that $x \in C_{i_j,j}$. If for each index $j$ we choose a unique index $i_j$, we can define a function $\varphi: J\to I$ by setting $\varphi(j)=i_{j}$. Then, for all $j \in J$, we have $x \in C_{i_j,j}$, which implies that $x$ belongs to $\bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i_j,j}$. Therefore, $x$ belongs to $\bigcup_{i\in \varphi(J)} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}$. On the other hand, since $\varphi(J)\subset I$, we have $$\bigcup_{i\in \varphi(J)} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}$$
With this, we conclude that
$$\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} = \bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$$
is true.

Answer (score 3):

The inclusion
$$\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$$ is valid and your proof is correct. However, the reverse inclusion
$$\bigcap_{j\in J} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}.$$
is false. Can you find a counterexample? (Hint: "If for each index $j$ we choose a unique index $i_j$")

Comment: hello. Could you explain me better the problem of choosing for each $j$ an index $i$ in $I$ such that $x\in C_{i,j}$? To me it seems clear that $x\in \bigcup_{i}C_{i,j}$ for every $j$ if $x\in \bigcap_{j} \bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i,j}$ .

Comment: Let me check that I really understand. Then inclusion is true if, and only if, the application $\varphi: J\to I$ is surjective. In other words $\varphi(J)=I$. Is this correct?

Comment: @EliasCosta Sorry, I misspoke. The problem occurs if a different $i$ is returned for every $j$. In that case $\bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i_j,j}$ need not be a subset of $\bigcup_{i\in \varphi(J)} \bigcap_{j\in J} C_{i,j}$, even if $\varphi(J)=I$.  For example, consider $I=J$ and define $C_{i,j}=\{1\}$ if $i=j$, and $C_{i,j}=\emptyset$ otherwise. For this collection we have $\varphi(j)=j$, hence $\varphi(J)=I$. Try to step through your argument with this collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the inclusion is correct. However your "proof" of the reverse inclusion is incorrect, since this equality does not hold. You can show this by counter-example. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1506070/771873